# How to add foreign key only if it does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

PostgreSQL database upgrade script adds foreign key constraint using commands:

```
update omrid set tellkanne=null where tellkanne =0 or tellkanne not in (select dokumnr from dok);

alter table omrid ADD constraint omrid_tellkanne_fkey  FOREIGN KEY (tellkanne)
 REFERENCES dok(dokumnr) ON UPDATE CASCADE on delete set null DEFERRABLE
```

`dokumnr` is dot table primary key with `serial` type.
both fields are `int` type

It takes lot of time if foreign key is already added before error is reported.
How to run those commands only if foreign key `omrid_tellkanne_fkey` does not exist ?

Comment: It would be easier to understand your question if you add your concerning tables DDLs.

Comment: How often do you need to add a foreign key constraint?

Comment: I need to add it during application upgrade. If new version is installed to customer site, upgrade script runs. It happens 1..30 times per year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query one of the information_schema views to see whether a constraint by that name exists.

```
select constraint_name 
from information_schema.referential_constraints
where constraint_name = 'omrid_tellkanne_fkey';
```

Whether this works reliably is application-dependent. Although this *will* reliably tell you whether a foreign key constraint named 'omrid_tellkanne_fkey' exists, it won't tell you whether that constraint is a foreign key constraint *between the tables you're interested in*.  You'll need to join one or two more tables from the information_schema views to get that.

A more general query might look like this.

```
select k.table_catalog || '.' ||
       k.table_schema || '.' ||
       k.table_name referencing_table,
       r.constraint_name,
       c.table_catalog || '.' ||
       c.table_schema || '.' ||
       c.table_name referenced_table
from information_schema.referential_constraints r
inner join information_schema.key_column_usage k
  on r.constraint_catalog = k.constraint_catalog
  and r.constraint_schema = k.constraint_schema
  and r.constraint_name = k.constraint_name
inner join information_schema.constraint_column_usage c
  on r.constraint_catalog = c.constraint_catalog
  and r.constraint_schema = c.constraint_schema
  and r.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
-- Change this WHERE clause to match your object names. 
where r.constraint_catalog = 'your_database'
  and r.constraint_schema = 'your_schema'
  and r.constraint_name = 'omrid_tellkanne_fkey'
  and k.table_name = 'omrid'
  and c.table_name = 'dok';
```